# R: Vectorized recoding values in one data frame based on another data frame

Tags: r, vectorization, recode

I have a data frame with a row of numbers and a row of letters. Let's call this the "decoder key." Each column in the decoder key represents a mapping between numbers and letters.

I also have a data frame with a column of codes comprised of numbers of varying digits. I want to create a new variable in this latter data frame that "translates" these codes from numbers to letters using the decoder key. In other words, I'll have the original number-based codes and then I'll have another column with the letters that correspond to that code.

I tried to implement this with a loop and `dplyr::recode()` but (a) I bet there's a better way to do this and (b) recode doesn't seem to work with the indexing. Any solutions? Below is a small reproducible example. In the real data, the `alphas`, `numbers`, and `codes` vectors are very large.

```
# Load packages
library(dplyr)

# Generate decoder
key <- data.frame(alphas = c("A","B","C"),
                  numbers = c("1","2","3"),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Generate codes from the possible values
# found in key$numbers
code_df <- data.frame(codes = c("2313","2","123","321"),
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Add "decoded value" to the codes table by
# converting any number in a code into the letter
# found above the code in the key data.frame. Loop
# through each possible number requiring decoding
# in the decoder table and replace it with the letter
# above it
for(i in 1:ncol(key)){
  code_df$codes <- dplyr::recode(x = code_df$codes, key[2,i] = key[1,i])
  }
```

Note: this is different from the following posts because I need to recode the variable rather than join two variables and I also have large enough data where I cannot do this manually.

[Changing value of data frame based on another data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7305312/changing-value-of-data-frame-based-on-another-data-frame)

[r language: how to create new column in data frame based on another data frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33466445/r-language-how-to-create-new-column-in-data-frame-based-on-another-data-frame)

[In R, how do you classify values in one data frame based on ranges in another data frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34427823/in-r-how-do-you-classify-values-in-one-data-frame-based-on-ranges-in-another-da)

Comment: Seems like `chartr` is relevant here.

Comment: Wow, never knew this existed in base R!  I'll give it a try shortly and post an answer.

Comment: You may find a suitable dupe among [these](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5br%5d%20chartr)

Comment: @Henrik Nice One!